# Why my android app is not running on detected device

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

Android studio has successfully detected my phone but I'm unable to run my app on my phone. When I tap run, nothing happens how do I solve this.

Comment: Observe if your project is building completely and see if you still have the problem check in the Logcat error logs if there is any error popping up

Comment: Please share your logcat error logs.